# How can I get create new columns in a dataframe that will take care of spillover rows?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, pivot

I have a pandas dataframe that looks like this:

| Name | Date | Item1 | Item2 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Andrew | 1/1/19 | Apple | Pear |
| Andrew | 1/1/19 | Orange |  |
| John | 2/5/20 | Banana |  |
| Steve | 2/3/21 | Grape | Apple |

The dataframe I am working with only has Item1 and Item2 columns, so if a person has a third item, a new row is created for that person with another Item1. I'd like to generate the same DataFrame, but by creating an Item3 column and keeping everything as one row per person. The result would look like this:

| Name | Date | Item1 | Item2 | Item3 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Andrew | 1/1/19 | Apple | Pear | Orange |
| John | 2/5/20 | Banana |  |  |
| Steve | 2/3/21 | Grape | Apple |  |

How can I accomplish this in pandas? Note, there can be spillover of up to 5 items per person, so I'll need up to an Item5.

Answer (score 2):

An approach

- generate list of all values for Name, Date pair
- expand it back into columns

```
df = pd.read_csv(io.StringIO("""Name    Date    Item1   Item2
Andrew  1/1/19  Apple   Pear
Andrew  1/1/19  Orange  
John    2/5/20  Banana  
Steve   2/3/21  Grape   Apple
"""), sep="\t")

# generate a column that is list of values
df = (df.groupby(["Name","Date"]).agg({c:lambda s: list(s.dropna()) for c in df.columns if "Item" in c}).reset_index()
 .assign(tmp=lambda dfa: dfa.Item1 + dfa.Item2)
 .drop(columns=[c for c in df.columns if "Item" in c])
)

# expand list into columns
df = df.loc[:,["Name","Date"]].join( df.tmp.apply(pd.Series).rename(columns={i:f"Item{i+1}" for i in range(5)}))
```

### output

```
  Name   Date  Item1  Item2 Item3
Andrew 1/1/19  Apple Orange  Pear
  John 2/5/20 Banana    NaN   NaN
 Steve 2/3/21  Grape  Apple   NaN
```

Answer (score 2):

```
delimiter = '####'
dfn = (df.set_index(['Name','Date']).stack()                 # stack to drop NA Item
    .reset_index(name='Item')
    .groupby(['Name','Date'])['Item'].agg(delimiter.join)    # for ('Name', 'Date') grouped, join item by delimiter
    .str.split(delimiter, expand=True)                       # split string, and expand
    .add_prefix('Item')                                      # rename columns with prefix 'Item'
    .reset_index()
)

print(dfn)


         Name    Date   Item0  Item1   Item2
    0  Andrew  1/1/19   Apple   Pear  Orange
    1    John  2/5/20  Banana   None    None
    2   Steve  2/3/21   Grape  Apple    None
```

---

method2:

```
dfn = df.set_index(['Name','Date']).stack()
obj = dfn.groupby(level=[0,1]).agg(list)
df_result = (pd.DataFrame(obj.tolist(), index=obj.index)
            .add_prefix('Item')
            .reset_index())

print(obj)

    Name    Date  
    Andrew  1/1/19    [Apple, Pear, Orange]
    John    2/5/20                 [Banana]
    Steve   2/3/21           [Grape, Apple]
    dtype: object


print(df_result)

        Name    Date   Item0  Item1   Item2
    0  Andrew  1/1/19   Apple   Pear  Orange
    1    John  2/5/20  Banana   None    None
    2   Steve  2/3/21   Grape  Apple    None
```